# How to plot the graph using MATLAB?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, dynamical-systems, graphing-functions, matlab

I've got the function $f_{i}(\phi) = \gamma_{i}+\sin(2\cdot \sin \phi)$ for $i = 1,2$ where $\gamma_1=0.01$ and $\gamma_2=0.02$

$\phi_{1}(0) = 0.1$ and $\phi_{2}(0) = 0.2$

$\dot{\phi_1} = f_1(\phi)+d\cdot \sin(\phi_2-\phi_1)$

$\dot{\phi_2} = f_2(\phi)+d\cdot \sin(\phi_1-\phi_2)$

where $d = 0.1$.

So there should be something for example the following table:

```
t     | ϕ1  | ϕ2
0.00  | 0.1 |0.2
0.01  | ... |...
0.02  | ... |...
...
100.00| ... | ...
```

And so using the received values it's needed to plot a graph by the coordinates

So the question is how to plot the function $\phi_2(\phi_1)$ on the the following graph using MATLAB?
[image]

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use Matlab?

Comment: What is $ϕ$ in the last two equations, in relation to $ϕ_{1,2}$?

Comment: @Rich_Rich actually no but I usually use it

Comment: @LutzLehmann ϕ is a the general function and $ϕ_{1,2}$ are specific function values

Comment: If $ϕ_{1,2}$ are specific function values, then what is their derivative? How are we to interpret the last two equations, as ODE system, or as conditions on a function at two fixed locations?

Comment: @LutzLehmann propably the second option. And so using the received values plot a graph by coordinates

Comment: This is a coding question. Please visit Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you mean $\dot{\phi_1} = f_1(\phi_\color{red}{1})+d\cdot \sin(\phi_2-\phi_1)$ and $\dot{\phi_2} = f_2(\phi_\color{red}{2})+d\cdot \sin(\phi_1-\phi_2)$? Because your equations (at the moment) dont make much sense except if we interpret the $\phi$ (the one without index) as an external scalar input. In this case, first the notation would be very misleading and second some assumptions on that input would be required. However I assume you just forgot the subscripts? In any case please clarify this and update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Solve instead

$$
\phi_1'(\phi_2) = \frac{f_1(\phi_1(\phi_2))+d\sin(\phi_1(\phi_2)-\phi_2)}{f_2(\phi_2)-d\sin(\phi_1(\phi_2)-\phi_2)}
$$

with initial conditions $\phi_1(0.2)=0.1$

Comment: thanks! but actually don't understand how to add this function to matlab